# Servlet JApplet: HttpSession

Tags: java, servlets, applet, httpsession

This sounds like a simple question but I can't find good information.

I'm writing a small JApplet that will be sending some info to a server servlet

I want to be able to track who is who so I want to put up a system of logging and and session.

I found some information about httpsession but I can never find one information:

Do I have to create a session object in my applet or is there an automatic system that creates the httpsession when I do something like this on the applet side

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection ();
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.connect();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of session at server in servlet.

and from java applet you need to maintain cookie in header while requesting.

**Also See**

- [Integrate an easy-to-use library for client-side cookie handling](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2002/jw-0426-cookie.html?page=3)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to this but I knew I was missing something

Comment: Please let me know if you stuck somewhere