# Session variables not working in Grails

Tags: session, grails

I try create new session in one controller and set variable and get this variable from session to another action. but session return null value. I use Grails 2.3.7.

```
class AuthorizationController {

    def signIn = {

       def session = request.getSession(true)
       session.setAttribute('username', 'zzzz')
       println(session.getAttribute('username')) // <-- here work
       redirect(action: logout)
    }

    def logout = {
        println(session.getAttribute('username')) // <-- here not work
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grails session variable null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134851/grails-session-variable-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code as:

```
class AuthorizationController {

    def signIn() {
       session.username = 'zzzz'
       println(session.username)
       redirect(action: 'logout')
    }

    def logout() {
        println(session.username)
    }
}
```

You don't have to create a new session, you can directly use `session` variable available to controllers. Also you don't have to use getters & setters to get & set values on session. You can directly use them as I've mentioned in above code.

If you are using grails > 2.x, avoid using closures in defining controller actions. Use plain method type instead.

Comment: Your code not work. But I try use avaible session with setters & getters. It's work.

Comment: Oh,Sorry. My fault. I had used `==` instead of `=` in my answer. I fixed it. Check it out. This will also work.

Comment: thanks. its work if use parentheses in redirect. like this: `redirect(action: logout())`

Comment: The syntax you specified above might be working but is not correct. Use `redirect(action: 'logout')`. Its the correct syntax. Actually I copied pasted from your answer. The syntax you provided was doing a method call `logout()` but the `action` argument must contain the name of the action to be redirected in string format.